# loading a common racket header into current toplevel

Tags: scheme, racket

There's a simple code section I'd like to share among a few racket scripts I wrote. I don't want to (require ..) it, but want to run it at top level (the common code includes calls to (current-command-line-arguments), etc. that a required module doesn't understand (at least I don't know if that's possible).

I try (load)'ing it, but it doesn't work as it was part of the current top-level context - I get an unbound identifier error in the loading context for a definition that's defined in the common header.

It seems I still don't understand some sections of the chapter 14 of the racket reference - I tried some examples of 14.1 (namespaces), 14.3 (racket/load) but couldn't get it working.

What am I missing? How can we make such a seemingly simple case work?

Edit: Here is an example from my case:

this is header.rkt:

```
#lang racket/load

(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or
                            (= (vector-length args) 0)
                            (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))

(define-syntax (if-prototyping stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ debug-expr non-debug-expr)
     (if PROTOTYPING
         #'debug-expr
         #'non-debug-expr))))

(if-prototyping
 (require (prefix-in "ci:" (file "/debugenvpath/utils.rkt")))
 (require (prefix-in "ci:" (file "/releaseenvpath/utils.rkt"))))

; arrange arguments
(define args (current-command-line-arguments))
(if-prototyping
 (set! args (if (= (vector-length args) 0)
                (vector "arg1")
                (vector (vector-ref args 1))))
 #t)
```

and this is a file that uses it (let's call this test.bat):

```
; @echo off
; "C:\Program Files\Racket\racket.exe" "%~f0" %*
; exit /b
#lang racket

(require "header.rkt")

"hello, args are: "
args
```

and running test.bat gives error below for the last line of the file:

```
args: unbound identifier in module in: args
```

#### Update2

OK, here is an update with phase1 (so-called macro-time) & phase0 (so-called runtime) expansion of my approach:

I can run (current-command-line-arguments) in phase1 (macro) when everything is in one file:

```
#lang racket

(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or
                                (begin
                                  (printf "phase1 expansion, args are: ~a\n" args)
                                  (= (vector-length args) 0))
                                (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))
(begin-for-syntax 
  (printf "phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: ~a\n" PROTOTYPING))

(define-syntax (if-prototyping stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ debug-expr non-debug-expr)
     (if PROTOTYPING
         #'debug-expr
         #'non-debug-expr))))

(if-prototyping
 (require (prefix-in "ci:" (file "./debug-env/util.rkt")))
 (require (prefix-in "ci:" (file "./release-env/util.rkt"))))

; arrange arguments
(define args (current-command-line-arguments))
(printf "phase0 expansion, args are: ~a\n" args)
(if-prototyping
 (set! args (if (= (vector-length args) 0)
                (vector "my-testing-arg-to-use-from-drracket")
                (vector (vector-ref args 1))))
 #t)

"util func call: "
(ci:f)
```

have util.rkt files for double checking:
debug-env/util.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide f)
(define (f) (display "f from debug"))
```

release-env/util.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide f)
(define (f) (display "f from release"))
```

and this is the output of the test run:

```
>test-commonheader.bat local arg1 arg2
phase1 expansion, args are: #(local arg1 arg2)
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #t
phase0 expansion, args are: #(local arg1 arg2)
"util func call: "
f from debug

>test-commonheader.bat arg1 arg2
phase1 expansion, args are: #(arg1 arg2)
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #f
phase0 expansion, args are: #(arg1 arg2)
#t
"util func call: "
f from release
```

it works as I expected. Now, the problem standing is, I can't put this whole logic in a common-header.rkt file to reuse. I'm just doing some more reading on Racket Reference 3.2 (Importing and Exporting), and there's a lot more that I should understand on require'ing for-syntax or directly to a phase level and provide'ing to phase-levels. I progressed a bit more with (for-syntax) in require and provide, but not there yet :/

#### update 3

It seems I was too busy trying to understand the phase-level extensions I missed the basics again. A simple (provide if-prototyping) from the header and (require "header.rkt") is actually working - but not perfectly :( . Alex was somehow correct in suggesting require should work. I was trying to (provide (for-syntax if-prototyping)) but that doesn't work because the if-prototyping is used at phase0 in the importing module.

Here's the latest header:

```
#lang racket

(provide if-prototyping)

(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or
                                (begin
                                  (printf "phase1 expansion, args are: ~a\n" args)
                                  (= (vector-length args) 0))
                                (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))
(begin-for-syntax
  (printf "phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: ~a\n" PROTOTYPING))

(define-syntax (if-prototyping stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ debug-expr non-debug-expr)
     (if PROTOTYPING
         #'debug-expr
         #'non-debug-expr))))

(if-prototyping
 (begin
   (require "debug-env/util.rkt")
   (provide (all-from-out "debug-env/util.rkt")))
 (begin
   (require "release-env/util.rkt")
   (provide (all-from-out "release-env/util.rkt"))))
```

and in the test-commonheader.bat I require the header:

```
(require "header.rkt")
```

now, a new problem is, header.rkt phase1 definitions run twice (which may be alright for this case - that's why I'll accept Alex's answer on using require):

```
>test-commonheader.bat arg1 arg2
phase1 expansion, args are: #(arg1 arg2)
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #f
phase1 expansion, args are: #(arg1 arg2)
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #f
phase0 expansion, args are: #(arg1 arg2)
#t
"util func call: "
f from release
```

Comment: Using `(current-command-line-arguments)` at a `for-syntax` level won't work. The decisions you make based on the command-line arguments need to be somehow delayed until run-time, when the command-line arguments are available.

Comment: But? I thought it is doing the right thing. I will test it tomorrow but shouldnt the code just start at phase1, get arguments, then choose the right (require) then compile the rest and continue at phase0?

Comment: One way to do that is with `load` but that requires basically an `eval`-based approach to almost all your files. However, there are still much better ways, especially since I'm guessing "file1.rkt" and "file2.rkt" provide the same bindings with the same purpose. The same interface. I'll update my answer this afternoon.

Comment: Ok @MattPeerson, I just updated my answer to add 3 different ways of doing something like this.

Comment: It seems the require part of my code was quite misleading. It seems I'm trying to define different environments for debug non debug cases, requiring same (or same interface) files from different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Addendum - follow up to the answer and discussions

Thanks to Alex's link for Matthew's [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/racket), I found one of the answers at 39:31. (require (for-syntax racket/base)) explains the missing part.

I'll briefly explain here. To start with, I must change the jargon of "compile time" and "run time" to phase1 & phase0. You can run any code at "any"-time with racket. You just have to put the necessary bindings into the scope that you're at.

When a code is running at a phaseN, it can run a compiled code or can do a syntax transformation, that's irrelevant - which means using the words "compile-time" and "runtime" will necessarily confuse people, just because of their stereotypical exposure to the phenomena using their inferior programming languages.

When you don't do any macro programming, everything is in phase0 (so-called runtime). Phases are in a way additions to your scopes in terms of how the bindings are maintained (probably a prefix to the identifiers of bindings, in a table where all the bindings live).

When a piece of code is run, it checks whether all the necessary bindings are reachable from it's scope. That means it doesn't matter if we're at phase0 (runtime), or phase1 (compile-time), or phaseN (runtime according to itself, compile-time according to phase(N-1)). What matters is whether the bindings are reachable from that phase. In our example question above, (current-command-line-arguments) is just a binding that needs to be brought to the current phase with some evaluation.

This is how we do it:

- If we want to use it at current phase, we (require racket/base) or since I never tried that, we rather use #lang racket/base.
- If we want to use it at current phase+1 (i.e. compile-time), we just (require (for-syntax racket/base)) to bring (current-command-line-arguments) into current phase+1.

let's see it in action:

If we try to use (current-command-line-arguments) in ..for-syntax.. forms, with only #lang racket/base, since it's not bound in phase1, it'll indicate it with an error:

```
#lang racket/base
(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or (= (vector-length args) 0)
                                   (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))
(begin-for-syntax
  (printf "phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: ~a\n" PROTOTYPING))
```

output of above is:

```
current-command-line-arguments: unbound identifier in the transformer environment;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: current-command-line-arguments
```

but if we add (2nd line) the necessary require:

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base))
(define-for-syntax args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define-for-syntax PROTOTYPING (or (= (vector-length args) 0)
                                   (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "local")))
(begin-for-syntax
  (printf "phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: ~a\n" PROTOTYPING))
```

then the output is (depends where you're running it from, here a drracket run to REPL is shown):

```
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #t
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #t
phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #t
```

Why does it depend, and why are there multiple lines? I'm not 100% sure, but have a feeling that it has something to do with the "Separate Compilation Warranty", Racket Reference 1.1.10.2. Because, as you can see the output we see is an "external" effect (output to an I/O device - this case the screen), which a separate compilation cannot guarantee to be stable (or bound?).

But (it seems?) if you want to do syntax-transformations with dynamic behaviour, by all means you can use:

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base))
```

or simply use below which does the above and some more (also increasing memory use of the session, of course):

```
#lang racket
```

Comment: Wait, does this actually work? Does it actually do different things depending on the command-line arguments you pass it?

Comment: Well, apparently. The example outputs are copy-paste from actual runs. And update3 in the question shows the different files (required) with different command line arguments

Comment: No, I know that it works in that sense, but how do you pass in different command-line arguments to the phase 1 code? How do you get a printout like `phase1, val for PROTOTYPING is: #f`?

Comment: Causality? The code runs from top to bottom, regardless of phase. At least that's what I deduced from ref chapter1-evaluation model. To get that print out i run the printf in (begin-for-syntax) scope. Ah, for #f, just pass some args, first one different than string "local". Like run shell: runme.bat arg1 arg2

Comment: Yes, but if I compile it first, then running it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: I use the windows script header at the beginning like the test.bat code in the question. Racket has to parse the rest of the file each time.

Comment: And when you're using for-syntax expansion in your code, you have to recompile the code that's using expansion results everytime the code expansion changes. But you can still call compiled code like (current-command-line-arguments) in syntax expansion.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use [`current-command-line-arguments`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29) at run-time, using [`require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-require.html) should work for that. Here's a simple example:

In common-code.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(current-command-line-arguments)
(current-command-line-arguments (vector "helloo"))
```

In file.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "common-code.rkt")
(current-command-line-arguments)
```

When file.rkt is run with the command-line arguments `these are my arguments`, it prints this:

```
'#("these" "are" "my" "arguments")
'#("helloo")
```

When a file is required another file, it is always run when the other file is run, and its run-time effects, including things like [`current-command-line-arguments`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29), are seen at run-time by the code the other file. Also, parameters like [`current-command-line-arguments`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29) are for the current script that is running, not the current file.

Alternatively, a slightly better way would be to make the common code a function, like this:

In common-code.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide setup)
(define (setup)
  (println (current-command-line-arguments))
  (current-command-line-arguments (vector "helloo")))
```

In file.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "common-code.rkt")
(setup)
(current-command-line-arguments)
```

This run with `these are my arguments` also prints out

```
'#("these" "are" "my" "arguments")
'#("helloo")
```

This way, file.rkt has more control over if/when/in-what-context `(setup)` gets called, and it can also can pass in arguments to the function (if you modify it to accept them), which can be very useful if you want the common code to rely on something from file.rkt.

### Update

With your updated question, the real problem seems to be that you want to require a different file depending on the command-line arguments. If there are no arguments or if the first argument is `debug`, you want the debugging version of the file, and if the first argument is anything else, you want the non-debugging version of the file.

The two versions of the file provide the same bindings with the same purpose, in other words, they have the same interface. And because they have the same interface, there are several ways to do this.

#### Functions

The way that uses the least magic is to have common-code.rkt provide a function which returns all of the functions from either the debug or non-debug versions:

non-debug.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide f g)
(define (f x)
  (add1 x))
(define (g x)
  (* 2 x))
```

debug.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide f g)
(require (prefix-in - "non-debug.rkt"))
(define (f x)
  (printf "(f ~v)\n" x)
  (-f x))
(define (g x)
  (printf "(g ~v)\n" x)
  (-g x))
```

common-code.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide return-f-and-g)
(define (return-f-and-g)
  (define args (current-command-line-arguments))
  (define debug? (or (= (vector-length args) 0)
                     (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "debug")))
  (cond [debug?
         (local-require "debug.rkt")
         (values f g)]
        [else
         (local-require "non-debug.rkt")
         (values f g)]))
```

file.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "common-code.rkt")
(define-values [f g]
  (return-f-and-g))
(f 2)
(g 2)
```

However, if debug.rkt and non-debug.rkt provide many functions, you'll have to enumerate all of them twice in common-code.rkt, and once in each file that you use it in.

#### The `dynamic-require` function

Another way to do this is with [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29). It would be used like this in common-code.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide f g)
(define args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define debug? (or (= (vector-length args) 0)
                   (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "debug")))
(define debug-on-non-debug (if debug? "debug.rkt" "non-debug.rkt"))
(define f (dynamic-require debug-on-non-debug 'f))
(define g (dynamic-require debug-on-non-debug 'g))
```

file.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "common-code.rkt")
(f 2)
(g 2)
```

However, this still leaves the problem of enumerating every single binding and writing a `(define f (dynamic-require debug-on-non-debug 'f))` line for each one.

#### Units

I said before that each of these methods was possible because debug.rkt and non-debug.rkt provided the same interface. One way of expressing that in racket is with [Units](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/units.html). They provide a way to package these things up into first-class values that can be chosen at run-time. [Units](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/units.html) have their own notion of an interface, called a [signature](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Signatures_and_Units.html).

You can declare the interface of the debug and non-debug files by using [`#lang racket/signature`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Whole-module_Signatures_and_Units.html). So in debug-or-non-debug-sig.rkt, put:

```
#lang racket/signature
f ; takes a number and adds 1 to it
g ; takes a number and multiplies it by 2
```

That defines the interface. It's good practice to also write comments specifying what `f` and `g` do, what they take as arguments, what they return, etc.

Then you have to declare that the debug and non-debug files implement that interface. You can do that with [`#lang racket/unit`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Whole-module_Signatures_and_Units.html) and the [`export`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingunits.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Funit..rkt%29._export%29%29) form.

non-debug-unit.rkt:

```
#lang racket/unit
(require "debug-or-non-debug-sig.rkt")
(import)
(export debug-or-non-debug^)
(define (f x)
  (add1 x))
(define (g x)
  (* 2 x))
```

debug-unit.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "debug-or-non-debug-sig.rkt")
(import)
(export debug-or-non-debug^)
(define (f x)
  (printf "(f ~v)\n" x)
  (add1 x))
(define (g x)
  (printf "(g ~v)\n" x)
  (* 2 x))
```

Then you can choose at run-time which of these files to use, with the form [`define-values/invoke-unit`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/invokingunits.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Funit..rkt%29._define-values%2Finvoke-unit%29%29).

common-code.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))
(require "debug-or-non-debug-sig.rkt"
         "debug-unit.rkt"
         "non-debug-unit.rkt")
(define args (current-command-line-arguments))
(define debug? (or (= (vector-length args) 0)
                   (equal? (vector-ref args 0) "debug")))
(define-values/invoke-unit (if debug? debug@ non-debug@)
  (import)
  (export debug-or-non-debug^))
```

file.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require "common-code.rkt")
(f 2)
(g 2)
```

If file.rkt is run with no command-line arguments or with `debug` as the first argument, it prints this:

```
(f 2)
3
(g 2)
4
```

But if it is run with any other arguments, it prints this:

```
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for my case. Maybe because I'm also using a for-syntax definition? I should add an example code for clarification, and apologies for not making it clear earlier.

Comment: Are you using the result of `(current-command-line-arguments)` in a macro?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am also using it in functions as well (by defining it twice, once for syntax another without). So I have one arg definition at phase1 and another at phase0 (since their contexts are different, it works).

Comment: Alex, thanks so much. You have put more time in the answer then I've for the question! I'll check your suggestions when I go home. I'm still trying to understand why I shouldn't mix phase1 and phase0 definitions and use one of your solutions instead. Well apart from mine not working in different files :/

Comment: It's not an issue of mixing phase 1 and phase 0 definitions. It's an issue of the `(current-command-line-arguments)` not being available at compile time, only at run time.

Comment: Do you know which section of the Racket Reference I should read to understand this compile and runtime phenomena?

Comment: Well, what best described it to me was [this talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/racket) by Matthew Flatt. One of the ideas in that talk was the idea that behavior of should be consistent whether you compile and run at the same time or you compile today and run tomorrow on another machine, or compile half the files now, and the other half later. This principle is the reason for the separate compilation guarantee, which is in the racket reference here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._separate-compilation%29

Comment: I found the place in the talk. He mentions it at about 12:50 as part of a larger example, which starts at about 5:00. The url is http://www.infoq.com/presentations/racket.

Comment: Thanks again, Alex. I checked the section you mentioned and even a bit more, and added some more explanations on why the approach works, as another answer to this question.